# TransformerFactory corrupts < input > and < br > tags inside < html > tag

Tags: java, xml, parsing

With simple code parsing and rewriting simple xml, some *strange* thing occurs with this

INPUT:

```
<html>
<input></input>
</html>
```

gives OUTPUT (**not well-formed**):

```
<html>
<input>
</html>
```

same thing occurs with < input/ >, or < br/ >.

It doesn't occur inside < html2 >, with other tags, ...

The code is classical:

```
// READ XML
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

// PARSE
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(_xml_source)));

// WRITE XML

TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(buffer));
String output = buffer.toString();
```

**It it a known bug ?**

Comment: Self-closing html tags immediately come to my mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT defines an [output method](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output), which can be `xml`, `html`, or `text`.

The specification says that the default output method should be `html` if the root node is `<html>`, otherwise it should be `xml`.

With the `xml` method, you will get `<input/>`.

With the `html` method, you will get `<input>`, *because the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1) says so*.

You can explicitly give the output method, if you want:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
```

So that a document with an `<html>` root node will output XML, i.e. `<input/>`.

**Quotes**

[XSLT output method](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output):

> The default for the `method` attribute is chosen as follows. If
>
> - the root node of the result tree has an element child,
> - the expanded-name of the first element child of the root node (i.e. the document element) of the result tree **has local part `html`** (in any combination of upper and lower case) and a null namespace URI, and
> - any text nodes preceding the first element child of the root node of the result tree contain only whitespace characters,
>
> **then the default output method is `html`; otherwise, the default output method is `xml`**. The default output method should be used if there are no `xsl:output` elements or if none of the `xsl:output` elements specifies a value for the `method` attribute.

[HTML empty tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1):

> Some HTML element types have no content. For example, the line break element `BR` has no content; its only role is to terminate a line of text. **Such *empty* elements never have end tags**. The document type definition and the text of the specification indicate whether an element type is empty (has no content) or, if it can have content, what is considered legal content.